# Updating an email's subject using Microsoft Graph in PHP

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Here's my current code:

```
require_once '/pathtovendor/vendor/autoload.php';

use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;
use Microsoft\Graph\Http\GraphRequest;

$access_token = "My valid access token";

$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($access_token);

$reply = array( "Comment" => "My reply" );
$message_id = "Valid message ID";

if($graph->createRequest("POST", "/me/messages/".$message_id."/reply")
      ->attachBody($reply)
      ->execute()){
        // I can get to this part OK. Message is replied to.

    //This code doesn't work
    $graph->createRequest("PATCH", "/me/messages/".$message_id)
      ->attachBody(array( "Subject" => "New Subject" ))
      ->execute();
}
```

I can run `GET` and `POST` requests which work, but I can't get `PATCH` to work this way. It continues to throw a `500 Internal Server Error`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only supported on draft messages. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_update):

> `subject` | String |
>   The subject of the message. **Updatable only if isDraft = true.**

The following properties can only be updated in draft messages:

- `bccRecipients`
- `body`
- `ccRecipients`
- `internetMessageId`
- `replyTo`
- `sender`
- `subject`
- `toRecipients`
- `from`

Comment: Just came across this.  You can use EWS.  Although Microsoft is pushing graph EWS will be around for a while yet.  The only thing thing they are doing is forcing OAuth OCT 2020.

Comment: There are several things that are still only supported by EWS. And for several scenarios, EWS is a solid path to head down (particularly if you're working with on-prem servers). That said, working with SOAP APIs in PHP isn't for the faint of heart. Unless you're in the "been-there-done-that" camp, I'm not sure I'd recommend it. It's a steep learning curve to climb only for an outdated framework.   ;)